# How to to map one range onto another?

Tags: functions, transformation

Take an arbitrary real function $f(x)$ with range $f(x) \ge 0$.

Is it possible to find an operator / function $g$ with the following mapping properties:

- $f(x)>1 \rightarrow 0<g(f(x))<1$
- $f(x)=1 \rightarrow g(f(x))=1$
- $0<f(x)<1 \rightarrow 0<g(f(x))<1$
- $f(x)=0 \rightarrow g(f(x))=0$?

I suspect not, but would very much appreciate any input.

Comment: Let $g:~\Bbb R_{\geq 0}\to\Bbb R_{\geq 0}$ be defined as $g(x) = \begin{cases}0.5&\text{if}~x>1\\1&\text{if}~x=1\\0.5&\text{if}~0<x<1\\0&\text{if}~x=0\end{cases}$.  There ya go, there's such an example of $g$.  (*Notice how similar it is to how you asked the question in the first place*).  If you want $g$ to have additional special properties, then you need to include those properties in the question.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that the presence of $f(x)$ isn't necessary. Just define a function $g$ over the domain $[0, \infty)$ (or beyond, if the mood takes you).

Comment: I’m obviously missing something. I don’t see a mathematical operation, just a somewhat-restated version of my question. I realise it’s me not you, but I simply don’t understand. It seems me that you’ve described the desired *outcome*, but my question was, what operations can make that actually *happen*? What am I missing?

Comment: Functions need not be defined using the usual operations. If you wish to restrict how we can build this function $g$ (maybe to composing certain operations, such as $+$, $-$, $\times$, $\div$, etc), then you should be clear about which ones are allowed and which ones aren't. For example, are we allowed to use, say, the function $\sin$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a nice smooth rational function that fits the bill:
$$g(x) = \frac{2x}{x^2 + 1}$$

Comment: Im new enough to maths that I didn’t realise I needed to be that specific. But smooth and rational is what I was after. So, thanks Theo. I’ll plug in some numbers when I get back to a computer and mark as answered assuming it fits the bill (as I’m sure it will).